# How can I do "version control" in vim?

Tags: vim, version-control

For example, I have a working code but not fast enough, so I want to record this version of the code and ten continue to optimize it, and maybe got a better version, then record this version again, so  on.

If I eventually failed to get a fast code, I want to roll back to the original working code.

I guess this could be achieved by using undo branch, but I didn't find how to do it.

Comment: Have you considered using the right tool for the job, a Version Control System? Such as subversion, git or mercurial, all of which are one-liners (and really short one-liners) to set up and use?

Comment: @thiton, it isn't really practical to set up a real version control system for every text file you write or edit on your system, furthermore you have to manage it. It's certainly the right thing to do, but it is nice to have a bit beefier undo history in vim for those cases where version control is overkill.

Comment: @HaskellElephant It is not a problem to put these files in a single repository since most (all I know) VCSes have ability to show only commits where certain path was modified.

Comment: @ZyX Have you really put `/*` into a git repo? I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: @kiltek This question talks about code, how is root directory relevant? I really have a VCS repository set up for any kind of code I am going to maintain for more then a few minutes. Normally *separate* repositories, but “one VCS repository for a collection of small unrelated scripts” is not a foreign concept for me either. Version control is rarely an overkill for a collection of text files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can add undo branches functionality that makes it more like a version control system.

In vim 7.3 you can have persistent undo, as described [here](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19548), you only need to add the following lines to your `.vimrc`.

```
set undodir=~/.vim/undodir
set undofile
```

To get the most of undo branches I highly recommend [gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/) since you can use it to visualize the tree and see the diffs of the commits.

Answer (score 7):

Use a version control system. I recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/) + [Fugitive](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2975).

Seriously!

You won't look back.

Answer (score 3):

Using a version control system is definitely a good idea for any projects you work on, even if they are fairly small. Even so, HaskellElephant makes a good point -- occasionally, you might experiment with a small throwaway script that you want to tweak. It might actually be pretty cool to be able to create save points on such occasions, so I played around with vim's `undotree()` function and came up with this script:

```
command! -nargs=1 StoreUndo call s:StoreUndo(<f-args>)
function! s:StoreUndo(label)
  if !exists('b:stored_undo_state')
    let b:stored_undo_state = {}
  endif

  let b:stored_undo_state[a:label] = undotree()['seq_cur']
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 -complete=custom,s:CompleteUndoStates RestoreUndo call s:RestoreUndo(<f-args>)
function! s:RestoreUndo(label)
  if !exists('b:stored_undo_state')
    let b:stored_undo_state = {}
  endif

  if !has_key(b:stored_undo_state, a:label)
    echoerr a:label.' not found in stored undo states.'
  endif

  exe 'undo '.b:stored_undo_state[a:label]
endfunction

function! s:CompleteUndoStates(A, L, P)
  if !exists('b:stored_undo_state')
    let b:stored_undo_state = {}
  endif

  return join(keys(b:stored_undo_state), "\n")
endfunction
```

Here it is in gist form: https://gist.github.com/1473170

You can put it under `~/.vim/plugin`, for example. Executing the command `:StoreUndo foo` will create a savepoint named "foo". You can make any changes you like. When you execute `:RestoreUndo foo`, the buffer will restore the saved state. The `RestoreUndo` command is tab-completed with all existing save points.

This is not persisted on file. If you close the buffer, you lose the history, so this could be only useful temporarily, for quick experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

There's plugins for vim.

Check also: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert with vim (in fact, I can barely use it), but the solutions that come to my mind are:

- Use an actual version control, that's what it's for. Maybe even one of them "distributed" flavours, since they don't need a separate repository;
- Just make a backup copy of your file/folder when you want to.
- You can even write a short program (shell script?) that copies the file/folder for you with an automatically appended suffix which marks the time when you made the copy.
- ... and then bind that program to a vim shortcurt (no idea how to do that, but vim is rumored to be so powerful, that I would imagine that it has such a feature).